# effect loop slider by ferro slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I change an effect loop in ferro slider .

you can see the slider at next link :
http://www.alessandroferrini.it/lab/jQueryPlugins/ferroSlider/demos/demo5.html#!div1

when you be in last image and click to next , it will go to first slide but as reverse and goes to left , can I change it to go to right with forward ?

Thanks

Comment: Have Contacted the person who did ferro slider and ask directly??? http://www.alessandroferrini.it/lab/jQueryPlugins/ferroSlider/docs/docs.php

Comment: Ok thanks , but if any person know please tell me .

Comment: I had a look at the options for this plugging and it doesnt look like it can do what you are asking. If you have a look at Public functions section it does not have direction for sliding, its either forward or backwards so it slides back through all the images as there in a container.

Comment: I had a look arround and wow slider seems to be what you want --- http://wowslider.com/simple-jquery-slider-gentle-linear-demo.html